# File shows multiple issues which is not known to me

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am creating an application with flutter and flutter_meedu and watching videos errors like these occur[enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: comma above the builder

Comment: point your pointer to the error, VSCode will display error.
actually you are missing required argument for the builder

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remove comma (,) from the params.